# Sticking two pictures together in python

Tags: python, image, python-3.x

Short question, I have 2 images. One is imported through:
`Image = mpimg.imread('image.jpg')`
While the other one is a processed image of the one imported above, this image is first converted from rgb to hls and then back. The outcome of this convertion gives a "list" which is different than the uint8 of the imported image.
When I'm trying to stick these images together with the function:

```
new_img2[:height,width:width*2]=image2
```

I don't see the second image in the combined image while by plotting the image through:

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(image2)
plt.show()
```

It works fine. What is the best way to convert the orignal to a "list" and then combine them or the "list" to uint8?

For some more information, the outcome has to be something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkbjd.png)

Where the right side is black because the image I try to import in it has another type of array. The left image was an uint8 while the other is a "list". The second image is this one, which is saved from python: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEEuK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of searching I found out that both variables can be changed to the type of a float64. The "list" variable:

```
Image = np.asarray(Image)
```

This creates an float 64 from a List variable. While the uint8 can be changed to a float64 by:

```
Image2=np.asarray(Image2/255)
```

Than the 2 can be combined with:

```
totalImgage = np.hstack((Image,Image2))
```

Which than creates the wanted image.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it the way you have show above but I have always been able to merge and save images as shown below!

```
def mergeImages(image1, image2, dir):
'''
    Merge Image 1 and Image 2 side by side and delete the origional

    '''
    #adding a try/except would cut down on directory errors. not needed if you know you will always open correct images
    if image1 == None:
        image1.save(dir)
        os.remove(image2)
        return 

    im1 = Image.open(image1) #open image
    im1.thumbnail((640,640)) #scales the image to 640, 480. Can be changed to whatever you need
    im2 = Image.open(image2) #open Image
    im1.thumbnail((640,480)) #Again scale
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (2000,720)) #Create a blank canvas image, size can be changed for your needs
    new_im.paste(im1, (0,0)) #pasting image one at pos (0,0), can be changed for you
    new_im.paste(im2, (640,0)) #again pasting
    new_im.save(dir) #save image in defined directory
    os.remove(image1) #Optionally deleting the origonal images, I do this to save on space
    os.remove(image2)
```

Comment: Only uses Image module

Comment: Well the problem is the second image is not an image that is saved on the computer. For example this is image 1 : http://www.irf.se/allsky/2015/20150216/jpgs/KRN20150216T212300E06000Q.JPG This image is processed so that only the green stuf is visible and all blue stuff is gone, to optimize the filter I would like to set the original picture left of the processed picture. But the output of the process is not a picture but a type of array known as "list".